# Connect points from different files with gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a variable number of files with a single row and 2 columns. I already plot the data in one window using

```
plot for [i=1:7] './data'.i.'.txt' using 1:2 with points
```

giving a point for each data point. But i'd like to have all points (from the different files) connected in the graph. How can i accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You can give shell commands from within gnuplot to aggregate the data files into one, for example:

```
plot '< cat data*.txt' using 1:2 with lines
```

Answer (score 1):

@meuh's solution is the simplest for Linux, however, for Windows you first would have to install the necessary utilities.
Therfore, for completeness, a **platform-independent gnuplot-only** solution (working from gnuplot 5.0 on).

**Script:**

```
### append several data files into one datablock
reset session

set table $Data
    plot for [i=1:7] sprintf('./data%d.txt',i) u 1:2 with table
unset table

plot $Data u 1:2 with lines
### end of script
```